# What does $Q$ refer to in this inequality $\Delta S\ge\frac{Q}{T}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, entropy, reversibility

Entropy change of a system due to heat $Q$ can be expressed by the following inequality (assuming that temperature is constant):

$$\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}\ge\frac{Q}{T} \tag{1}$$

It can be expressed more explicitly as

$$\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}=\frac{Q}{T}+\sigma \tag{2}$$

where $\sigma$ represents extra entropy generated during an irreversible process. It follows that $Q$ satisfies this inequality

$$Q\le T\Delta S_\mathrm{sys} \tag{3}$$

This might a trivial question but I am confused about what exactly $Q$ refers to: reversible heat flow $Q_\mathrm{rev}$ or net heat flow $Q_\mathrm{net}$? I initially believed it was the former but if we discuss about available work due to the change in free energy, I think it makes more sense to interpret $Q$ as net heat flow. If $Q$ is the net heat flow, then $T\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}$ will be considered as reversible heat flow and (2) becomes

$$Q=T\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}-T\sigma=Q_\mathrm{rev}-T\sigma\tag{4}$$

It still satisfies the inequality (3):

$$Q\le Q_\mathrm{rev} \tag{5}$$

Now for a system in contact with thermal reservoir of temperature $T$, the change in its Helmholtz energy is

$$\Delta F=\Delta U-T\Delta S=Q-W-T\Delta S_\mathrm{sys} \tag{6}$$

by the first law of thermodynamics. I interpret $Q$ here as the net heat flow $Q_{net}$. Substituting $Q$ using (4) yields

$$\Delta F=Q_\mathrm{rev}-T\sigma-W-T\Delta S_\mathrm{sys} \tag{7}$$

Since $Q_\mathrm{rev}=T\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}$,

$$\Delta F=-T\sigma-W \tag{8}$$

$$W=-\Delta F-T\sigma \tag{9}$$

We see that the work that can be extracted by a system satisfies $W\le -\Delta F$ as expected. I don't think I can derive this inequality without assuming that $Q$ is net heat flow.

Did I misunderstand anything?

The inequality $Q\le T\Delta S$ is ambiguous. I interpret it either $Q\le Q_\mathrm{rev}$ or $Q_\mathrm{rev}\le Q$.

Comment: How do you define *reversible* and *irreversible* heat flow? I am not even sure that this is a meaningful distinction, since I do not recall ever seeing it...

Comment: @RogerVadim The heat flow is reversible if $Q_\mathrm{rev}=T\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}$. But I think it is still ambiguous since the change in entropy of a system is the sum of reversible and irreversible contributions: $\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}=\Delta S_\mathrm{rev}+\Delta S_\mathrm{irrev}$. So maybe the better definition would be $Q_\mathrm{rev}=T\Delta S_\mathrm{rev}$.

Comment: It seems to me like a redefinition: the process is reversible (and hence the heat flow is reversible) if  $Q=T\Delta S$, and it is irreversible, if $Q<T\Delta S$. What changes here is the change in entropy, not the heat flow - which is the same.

Comment: @RogerVadim I believe by reversible heat it is meant heat where the temperature difference is infinitesimal and irreversible heat where the temperature difference is finite.

Comment: @BobD Could be. But the Clausius inequality is more general - irreversibility may come not only from the finite difference in temperatures. $T$ is the environment temperature.

Comment: @RogerVadim I was only referring to the difference between reversible heat transfer and irreversible heat transfer, not all types of irreversibility

Answer (score 0):

Forget "heat" flow and instead always think of "entropy" flow. An entropy ("heat") reservoir at temperature $T^0$ is one that can lose entropy or absorb entropy in any amount but its temperature never changes, and if its entropy changes by $\Delta S^0$ at temperature $T^0$ then its energy also changes by exactly $T^0\Delta S^0$.

When you connect a "system" to this reservoir no matter what you do the reservoir's own process is always reversible, but not so the system's. The reservoir is very big and the system is very small...

By the 1st law if the reservoir loses $\Delta S^0$ entropy and if that entropy is absorbed by the "system" then the reservoir loses $\Delta E^0=T^0\Delta S^0$ thermal energy that is absorbed by the system. And this $\Delta E^0$ is *exactly* equal the internal energy change caused by the system being connected to the reservoir at temperature $T^0$. If the system also delivers or absorbs work $\Delta W^0$, as measured from the *outside*, then its internal energy changes according to $\Delta E = \Delta E^0 + \Delta W^0$ irrespective of whether the process is reversible or irreversible.

But entropy is not a completely conserved quantity, or better said it is conserved from one end. The system's own entropy $S$ may also be increasing by absorbing $\Delta S^0$ *and* by the internally generated entropy that depends on the specific of the absorption process. The 2nd law says that $\Delta S \ge \Delta S^0$ or $\Delta S = \Delta S^0 +\sigma$ where $\sigma \ge 0$ is the internally generated entropy. You get equality, $\sigma = 0$, if and only if the process is *reversible* an dyou get inequality of the process is irreversible. The amount of $\sigma$ internally generated by the process in the system is process dependent but it is characteristic to it. For example, a current $I$ passing through a resistor $R$ at temperature $T$ will generate entropy at the rate of $\dot \sigma =\frac{RI^2}{T}$ and this rate can be measured directly.

Finally, the internal energy change $\delta E = \delta E^0 + \delta W^0$ is written with external parameters but it can be written with internal parameters of the system itself as $\delta S = \delta S^0 +\sigma$ and $\delta E = T\delta S + \delta W$ where $\delta W = \sum_k \frac{\partial E}{\partial x_k} \delta x_k$. This form of the system's energy change is between two nearby equilibrium states, so then $T=T^0$ and since $\sigma \ge 0$ you must also have $\delta W^0 \ge \delta W$ expressing the *degradation* of work, or free energy, by irreversibility.